# Ignore the service availability during start nginx in docker swarm

Tags: docker, nginx

The application makes up of serveral services in front of which we use nginx as the web server. And we deploy all these services inclulding nginx by in docker swarm.

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  sa:
    image: xx.com/service-a
  sb:
    image: xx.com/service-b
  sc:
    image: xx.com/service-c
  ....
  gateway:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - /nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
networks:
  overlay:
```

nginx.conf:

```
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://sa;
  }

  location /sb/ {
    proxy_pass http://sb;
  }

  location /sc/ {
    proxy_pass http://sc;
  }
  ......
```

So far so good, however when start the stack and if one of the service(say it is `sc`) fail to start, it will cause the `nginx` fail to start too which make our whole application unavailable.

Seems like that the embed-ed dns server by docker can not resolve the host `sc` since it is not started yet.

We do not want a single service affect the whole application, and sounds like this can be described as another question: "how to let nginx ignore the availability of the upstream/proxy during start". While after searching no solution. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the dns resolution , until you need it .
So nginx can restart without doing dns resolution .

you must use a variable in your `proxy_pass`directive  .

```
...
set $backend "http://serviceD" ;
proxy_pass $backend;
...
```

So i was able to simulate your problem with this `docker-compose.yaml` and th following `default.conf`

in the nginx image , the default resolver is pointing to 127.0.0.11

```
resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
resolver_timeout 5s;

server {
listen 0.0.0.0:80;
server_name localhost;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://serviceA;
}

location /sd/ {
    set $backend "http://serviceD" ;
    proxy_pass $backend;
}

}


version: '3.7'
services:
  serviceA:
    image: debian:stretch-slim
    command: ["sleep","3600" ]
  serviceD:
    image: debian:stretch-slim
    command: ["sleep","3600" ]
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c","exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
    restart: always
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
  testD:
    image: alpine:latest
    restart: always
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c","( apk add --no-cache bind-tools && host serviceD && ping -c 8 -i 4 serviceD )" ]
```

Comment: The `service-a` is my typo.

Comment: i modified my answer a second time